# Switch Button After Clicked With AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

When I click button "on" my API run xhr to "activate" my data. But when I click button "off" my API run XHR to "deactive" my `data.isactive` I got from data API(0 or 1). Therefore, I use _

> ng-show and ng-hide

I did show my button "off" or "on" to show if my `isactive === 1` or `isactive === 0`.

**I used this code HTML :**

```
<button ng-show="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> Off</button>
<button ng-hide="data.active" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="FiturThread(data)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> On</button>
```

My problem is i clicked button "on" and alert run "Success Active" , button "on" should be replaced with button "off", so instead.

Can you give me solution ? I had to use what ? Thank you

Comment: Your html looks fine, there must be a problem with the data, I would suggest inspecting the response you get from your xhr call in the browser.

Comment: The response xhr is correct and expected as I want

Comment: I think result is the array of data and you write ng-repeat to perform active/inactive to each data. Inside of that ng-repeat, buttons stay. I understood this. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, right. I mean that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   
</script>                 

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-show="data.active" ng-click="FiturThread(data)">First Button</button>
        <button ng-hide="data.active" ng-click="FiturThread(data)">Second Button</button>
    </div>

    <script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

           $scope.data = {};
           $scope.data.active = true;
           $scope.FiturThread = function(){
             $scope.data.active = !$scope.data.active;
         }

     });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code not showing error but still not working. Button not switch and the console.log is good and nothing error

Comment: show me more code so that I will able to understand

Comment: I just use "ng-repeat="data in result" " to get "data.active" and html.
That's it.